# How to speed up a non-built in function? How to make MaxPool operation by using an elliptical or circular kernel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, max-pooling

I wrote a code that does MaxPool operation on tensors. In this code, I used two for loops to move the kernel on the matrix. However, when I ran this code, I saw that the code I wrote was running 50 times slower than the ready function. You can see my own function as follows:

```
    kernel = np.ones((k,k))
    p = round(0.5*(k-1))
    pA = np.pad(image, ((p,p),(p,p)), 'constant')
    dilated_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    for i in range(image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(image.shape[1]):
            dilated_image[i,j] = np.multiply(pA[i:i+k,j:j+k],kernel).max()
    return dilated_image
```

You can see the results as follows:

Timing result of my own function:
[image: Timing result of my own function]

Timing result of Tensorflow MaxPool function:
[image]

What do you think could be the cause of such a problem and how can I speed up this code? Moreover, is there any way to do make an elliptical kernel in MaxPool operation in tensorflow?

Comment: Very generally spoken, you could apply parallelization by using multiprocessing library with e.g. Pool. However, without being sure, I assume that Tensor is implemented in C just wrapped to Python, which is a main source of speedup

Comment: @FloLie thanks for the quick response. Do you know a way to make Max Pooling with an elliptical kernel in Tensorflow?